# OS X tool for animating Git commands on local repository?

Tags: osx, git

**Question**

OS X: Is there a tool for OS X that visualizes my Git commands on my local Git repositories with animations?

I'm not looking for a Git client, such as [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which can visualize the branches.

**Examples**

Web: [LearnGitBranching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/?demo) visualizes Git commands with beautiful animations.

[image]

Windows: [SeeGit](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/03/15/visualize-git-with-seegit.aspx/) visualizes Git commands on one's own repositories with nice animations.

[image]

I'm looking for something similar for OS X.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of GUI git clients for OS X, but none feature the animation that either of your Windows or Web examples provide.

Most, if not all, feature a email app-esque interface, with a list pane on the left, along with a submissions list pane, and then a couple of central panes for the current edit item. The main contenders of this type of GUI are (in no particular order):

- [GitHub](http://mac.github.com);
- GitX - various forks - [GitX - Rowanj](https://github.com/rowanj/gitx), [GitX (L)](http://gitx.laullon.com/), or [GitX -
  Pieter](http://gitx.frim.nl/);
- [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/);
- [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com);
- [Gitbox](http://gitboxapp.com).

I would imagine that you have seen these GUI app roundups already, but I will list them here:

- [Git GUI Clients for OS X](http://undefinedvalue.com/2013/02/28/git-gui-clients-os-x) -  A basic text only review site, recommends [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), and [GitHub](http://mac.github.com) for beginners
- [The Best Mac Git Gui](http://blog.hswolff.com/the-best-mac-git-gui/) - A good review, with screenshots - recommends [GitX - Rowanj](https://github.com/rowanj/gitx)

So, in short, so far, there is not a *native* animated git app for OS X... yet.

Of course, while you wait for a native app to be developed, you could always easily wrap your Windows based [SeeGit](https://github.com/Haacked/SeeGit) example in a [Wineskin](http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php) so that you can run it on OS X.